# Bug? v12.0.4 Account Console loading

Tags: keycloak

Is there a bug with respect to Keycloak v12.0.4 ?

It is hanging on `'Account Console loading ...'`.

HTTP sequence on clicking 'Impersonate' on all realms below. NB: https://example.com/authjs/keycloak.js is a 404 NOT FOUND.

POST https://example.com/auth/admin/realms/master/users/3467c293-741d-4345-8e06-a2a17ea71458/impersonation HTTP/1.1

GET https://example.com/auth/realms/master/account HTTP/1.1

GET https://example.com/auth/realms/master/account/ HTTP/1.1

GET https://example.com/authjs/keycloak.js HTTP/1.1

GET https://example.com/auth/resources/d5e5y/account/keycloak.v2/welcome-page-scripts.js HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right this is a bug that according to the Keycloak mailing list is currently being tracked by the following stories:

- [authjs/keycloak.js 404 NOT FOUND related stories](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-16709?jql=text%20%7E%20%22%2Fauthjs%2Fkeycloak.js%22%20ORDER%20BY%20lastViewed%20DESC);
- [Infinite loop logging as an user or impersonating an user as admin](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-17074).

Answer (score 1):

The `authjs/keycloak.js` 404 NOT FOUND error on 12.0.x is related to this bug [https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-16709?jql=text%20~%20%22%2Fauthjs%2Fkeycloak.js%22%20ORDER%20BY%20lastViewed%20DESC](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-16709?jql=text%20%7E%20%22%2Fauthjs%2Fkeycloak.js%22%20ORDER%20BY%20lastViewed%20DESC) - you just need a leading `/` on `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL` and it fixes it.

Comment: +1, Yep, you were right, strange I got the wrong information from someone in the redhat xD, i have also update my answer